# In Shopify Liquid, is there a way to output some products that match a vendor?

Tags: shopify, liquid

On a product page, I have the product's vendor name in `product.vendor`.

I want to output some more products from the same vendor.

Is there a way to output some more products from the same vendor, without having to manually create a smart collection with those products?

Comment: Maybe with `all_products`

The `all_products` object contains a list of all the products in your store.

Answer (score 1):

On my mind this can't be achieved without Ajax query.

You may access a list of products from a vendor by querying the URL:
 /collections/vendors/?q={{ product.vendor }}

I've not tested what is returned by default for the JSON view:
 /collections/vendors/?q={{ product.vendor }}&view=json

Doc reference: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/collection#collection-current_vendor

Answer (score 0):

The easiest recipe I can think of is to do the following:

- make a smart collection, where the smart is to use the vendor you want

Now when you want to show products all from that vendor, simply show that collection. You also get all the vendors in a shop as shop.vendors, so you could use that list to make your vendor selection process easy on customers.

Do not use Ajax for this. That is silly, slow and not very Shopify-theme-ish!

Comment: Do I have to make a smart collection for each vendor?

Comment: Of course. If that troubles you, just know that you can script that in just a few lines of code and automate the process. Such is the beauty of Shopify.